# Custom Post Type Not working like a Post?

Tags: custom-post-types

Okay - This may be a little elementary for some but I'm a bit confused here, and would love some insight. I have two sections of my website - my "Lessons" section, which is my main posts page, and an "Arrangements" section, which is a custom post type that I'm trying to get to act like my "Lessons" page, the Arrangements section doesn't show an Author, or Breadcrumbs.

For an example, see the following site: [Personal Site](https://tylerdelsack.com)

### Problem:

On my Lessons section, I can see breadcrumbs:

[image: Correct Breadcrumbs]

And my author section comes up on single posts:
[image: Author]

On the Arrangements section, the breadcrumbs do not work if you click through to a post, and neither does the Author Section.

Breadcrumbs should be "Home | Arrangements | Summertime", instead they look like:

[image: Breadcrumbs]

And author section is missing.

[image: Author Section]

Any ideas? Here's what I have so far:

---

My Lessons section is controlled by my `index.php`.

My Arrangements section is controlled by a custom Template file called `arrangements.php`.

In the `arrangements.php` file, I have the following loop:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'arrangements',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);

$new_post_loop = new WP_Query($args);
?>
<main id="primary" class="site-main">

    <?php
    if ($new_post_loop->have_posts()) :

        while ($new_post_loop->have_posts()) :

            $new_post_loop->the_post();

            get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'blog');

        endwhile;

        the_posts_navigation();

    else :

        get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'none');

    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    ?>
```

Comment: WordPress does not have breadcrumbs, this will be provided either by a plugin or a theme, but even if it did, your arrangements post archive is not actually a arrangements archive, it's a page that has the same name that then pretends to be a arrangements archive by ignoring the main query. If you want your arrangements post archive to appear at a particular URL, there are solutions for that. Use `archive-arrangements.php` and adjust `register_post_type` so it uses that permalink

Comment: Hey Tom, I'm using them through Yoast. Okay, I'll give that a try!

Comment: You'll need to speak with Yoast dev support for the breadcrumbs part

Comment: Well, I copied my template file `arrangements.php` over to `archive-arrangements.php`, but I think I've found my problem. As I set a `page` with a template of `arrangements.php`, it's still drawing from `page.php`, not `archive-arrangements.php`. I'm unable to select an archive from a menu...I think?

Comment: You can set a URL. The name of the template file is coincidental though. The template does not determine the query, it's the other way around. E.g. if you intercepted the query and set `s` and unset some other flags, WordPress would instead think it's a search index and load `search.php`. In fact, when WordPress queries the database, it hasn't even attempted to pick a template file yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare your "Arrangements" custom post type, be sure to add 'author' and 'breadcrumbs' as parameters to the "supports" array. For example, it might look something like:

```
        $supports = array(
            'title',
            'author',
            'breadcrumbs',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'thumbnail',
            'comments',
            'custom-fields',
            'revisions',
        );


        $labels = array(
            'name'                  => 'Arrangements',
            'singular_name'         => 'Arrangement',
            'menu_name'             => 'Arrangements admin menu'),
            'name_admin_bar'        => 'Arrangements add new on admin bar',
            'add_new'               => 'Add New Arrangement',
            'add_new_item'          => 'Add New Arrangement',
            'new_item'              => 'Add New Arrangement',
            'edit_item'             => 'Edit Arrangement',
            'view_item'             => 'View Arrangement',
            'all_items'             => 'All Arrangements',
            'search_items'          => 'Search Arrangements',
            'parent_item_colon'     => 'Parent Arrangement:',
            'not_found'             => 'No Arrangement Found',
            'not_found_in_trash'    => 'No Arrangements found in trash',
            'filter_items_list'     => 'Filter Arrangements',
            'items_list_navigation' => 'Arrangements list navigation',
            'items_list'            => 'Arrangements list',
        );      

        $args = array(
            'labels'          => $labels,
            'supports'        => $supports,
            'public'          => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'rewrite'         => array( 'slug' => 'arrangements', 'with_front' => false ),
            'menu_position'   => 2,// or whatever
            'menu_icon'       => ( version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '3.8', '>=' ) ) ? 'dashicons-admin-generic' : false ,// or whatever
            'has_archive'     => true,
        );

        register_post_type( 'arrangement', $args );
```

That should sort out the author section display issue. Hopefully it will address the breadcrumbs as well. If not, then as another user suggested, the Yoast breadcrumbs may involve additional complexity.

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/registering-custom-post-types/

Comment: I got it now - thanks so much! I appreciate the help here.